# Watson Assistant: Prevent being locked into an action buttons

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I'm using the Watson Assistant Actions and I have an action that gives the following response.

```
Here are some related topics... 

[Order new card]    [Order additional card]    [Nevermind]
```

The buttons when clicked are check and a sub action is called for that Action.

The problem is that the user is trapped unless they click `Nevermind`. I would like a way for them to ask a different question without getting the "I don't understand".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom [option response](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-option) in the JSON editor. Click the `</>` in the top right of the response box.

The following JSON block below will simulate the same thing. Instead of having to check for the response though it allows the user to fall through and look up the intent directly. Reducing the complexity of the action.

```
{
  "generic": [
    {
      "title": "Here are some related topics...",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Order new card",
          "value": {
            "input": {
              "text": "Order new card"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "label": "Order additional card",
          "value": {
            "input": {
              "text": "Order additional card"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "response_type": "option"
    }
  ]
}
```